# Change title bar text color in radForm using telerik

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am using the Telerik rad form and i have customized the color of the title bar using the below code

```
this.FormElement.TitleBar.FillPrimitive.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(52, 52, 52);    
this.FormElement.TitleBar.FillPrimitive.GradientStyle = Telerik.WinControls.GradientStyles.Solid;
this.FormElement.TitleBar.BorderPrimitive.BoxStyle = Telerik.WinControls.BorderBoxStyle.SingleBorder;
this.FormElement.TitleBar.BorderPrimitive.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(52, 52, 52);
```

But now i need to change the color of the title bar text. Is it possible..?

[image]

title bar text is **Rad Form 1**, but it not visible and i need to change its color to white ? How to do it..?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ForeColor` property of the `FormElement.TitleBar`:

```
this.FormElement.TitleBar.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

**Update**

It should work if you set the Rad form like this:

```
public frmMain()
{
    new VisualStudio2012LightTheme();
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ThemeName = "VisualStudio2012Light";
}

private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormElement.TitleBar.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: have just copied and pasted your code and it doesn't work for me]

Comment: It works but i dont want to change the theme , because i need my title bar to be appear in black color where the text and close (x) icon should be in white color. If i change theme to VisualStudio2012Light it make sfornt white and close (x) icon to black.I nned both font and close icon in white color and title bar in my custom color

Comment: @dahsra It's just an example. you can set it to whatever themes you like.

Comment: No what am telling is if i change it to anyother theme than what you suggested  the font color is not getting white

Answer (score 1):

RadTitleBar has a TextPrimitive to handle its text. You can set the ForeColor to it:

```
this.FormElement.TitleBar.TitlePrimitive.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```